# How to insert a new Row in Excel sheet using Microsoft.Ace.Oledb in VS 2012 using c#

Tags: c#, insert, oledb, excel-2010, ms-jet-ace

I'm doing the following to insert a row in an excel sheet using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB as a provider in c# code:
1- I have the following connection string:

```
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.xlsx;Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=False;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;HDR=YES""");
```

2- And the following code to insert:

```
        string strSQL = "INSERT INTO [sheet1$] (Id, Name, parentId) VALUES(196,'test',1)";
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        excelConnection.Open(); 
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, excelConnection);
        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbCommand.Dispose();
        excelConnection.Close();
        excelConnection.Dispose();
```

But once I run my code i have the following OleDbException exception, when opening the connection:

```
Could not find installable ISAM
```

I did my search and found that it's related to a bad connection string format, so after several try i found that when i removed "ReadOnly=False;" from the connection string the OleDbException exception changed to:

```
Operation must use an updateable query
```

When executing the command "dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery"; so i also did my search and found that it's a permission issue so i gave the Excel file a total permission to be modified by the user group "Everyone", but still have the same exception. 
I'm really lost here, i tried so many things and i would appreciate any help; i'm pretty sure it's a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with your code: it seems to work if your remove the 'Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=False;' of the connection string.